# AWS Boto3(Python): how to save multiple response from multiple image input to individual file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rekognition

The below code is for AWS Rekognition image label detection.

Question 1) Since AWS Recognition can only run one image at a time, I used [List] to add multiple images at a time. However, what if I want to run 100 images? this means I have to manually write name for 100 images in that [List] which will take forever. What is the best way to solve this issue supposing I have 100 images named image1, image2, image3, ... image100?

Question 2) The below code will save the response for all 3 images to a single JSON file. How can the response be saved into an individual file?

```
# List to record all the responses    
responselist=[]
list=['picture1.jpg','picture2.jpg','picture 3.jpg'] 
for image in list :
    response = client.detect_labels(
    Image={
    'S3Object': {
    'Bucket': 'test1',
    'Name': image
        }})
    responselist.append(response)

print(response)

# JASON file Save
json_file = json.dumps(response)
Path('rekognition_test.json').write_text(json_file)
```

Comment: you can read all the images from a directory(i.e S3 objects path) using `list_objects` with certain extensions like `*.jpg` and with regards to save to json you can use the image name to add json extension to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted does not do what you think it does.
Specifically, it **does not save** results from
the three images. Only the last `response` is
saved.

This is because you are creating  a`responselist`
which is simply not used at all. Also don't call your
list a `list` as it is a python's actual [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) data structure.

However, if you want to write results for each image separately
you can try the following :

```
my_list=['picture1.jpg','picture2.jpg','picture 3.jpg'] 

for image in my_list:

    response = client.detect_labels(
                  Image={
                  'S3Object': {
                  'Bucket': 'test1',
                  'Name': image
                }})

    json_file = json.dumps(response)
    Path(f"{image}.json").write_text(json_file)
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried the provided code but it only saves the last image (in this case 'picture 3.jpg') response as JSON file instead of all three. Any idea?

Comment: @Sun-HoRo Double check your indentation. If its wrong, this would explain why only last image is saved.